# Ideapad 310 wifi problems with QCA9377 chipset

Tags: drivers, lenovo, 16.10, atheros, ideapad

Bought myself a nice new Ideapad 310, but I'm having wifi issues. I know it's not the card itself as it's working fine in Windows.

A little bit of console output:

`~> lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; dmesg | grep ath10k
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:3854]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:4035]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
[   10.702934] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   11.468134] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   11.468143] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   11.559070] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca9377 hw1.0 target 0x05020000 chip_id 0x003820ff sub 17aa:4035
[   11.559071] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   11.559442] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 api 5 features ignore-otp crc32 79cea2c7
[   11.882651] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 93da0176
[   13.700701] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[   13.892802] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   54.550452] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[   54.807511] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[   87.131551] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[   93.416750] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!`

I suspect that "Direct firmware load failed" is part of the problem! I've tried installing the drivers from the github repo as well, but to no avail.

If I unplug the network cable and let wifi take over, it can see the various networks around, will attempt to connect, and then just show the password dialog again (and yes, I've double checked I've got the right pass!). The more annoying part is that if I do that and then plug the ethernet cable back in, it doesn't switch back to wired, and I end up having to reboot.

This is what's in dmesg if I do that:

`[  902.852708] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  918.605406] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: link down
[  926.759851] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  938.917562] wlp2s0: authenticate with 94:44:52:2d:7c:cd
[  938.950373] wlp2s0: send auth to 94:44:52:2d:7c:cd (try 1/3)
[  938.951626] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  938.953669] wlp2s0: associate with 94:44:52:2d:7c:cd (try 1/3)
[  938.955960] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 94:44:52:2d:7c:cd (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[  938.958987] wlp2s0: associated
[  938.959060] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[  938.965286] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x833a
[  938.965287] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[  938.965288] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[  938.965290] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[  938.965291] ath: Country alpha2 being used: GB
[  938.965291] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[  938.965293] ath: regdomain 0x833a dynamically updated by country IE
[  942.133768] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: timed out waiting for offchannel skb ffff9f18ecc7b300
[  945.205307] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: timed out waiting for offchannel skb ffff9f18ecc7b300
[  948.277398] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: timed out waiting for offchannel skb ffff9f18ecc7b300`

Any ideas or suggestions gratefully appreciated. According to [this discussion](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/ath10k/2016-October/008612.html) the error message might indicate the driver isn't able to find the firmware to upload. Is it possible to increase the log level so that it prints where it's trying to load it from?

Edit: Might just be falling victim to a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1634681). Time for a cheap USB dongle to tide me over.